# Question about isomorphism of Hilbert Spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Following is a question from Rudin :

> Given Hilbert Spaces $H_1$ and $H_2$ show that one of them is isomorphic to a subspace of the other.

My thought process : wlog say $H_1$ has algebraic dim $\leq$ algebraic dim of $H_2$.
I took a Hilbert Basis of $H_1$ and mapped it injectively to a subset of a basis of $H_2$

How do I extend this to a Hilbert Space isomorphism i.e preserve inner products?

Comment: Choose Hilbert bases instead.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Hilbert bases are what I took. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Which Rudin book is this from?

Comment: Real and Complex Analysis, chapter 4

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person Are you using this book for self-study?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**: Let $\{e_s: s \in S\}$ be an orthonormal base for $H_1$ and $\{f_t: t \in T\}$ be an orthonormal basis for $H_2$. Without loss of generality, assume $|S| \leq |T|$. I.e. there is an injection $\iota: S \hookrightarrow T$. Show that there is a linear isometry
$$\psi: H_1 \to H_2$$
such that $\psi(e_s) = f_{\iota(s)}$ for all $s \in S$.

Comment: This is a nice answer. Orthonomality is what I missed in my thought process.
I also read the previous answer (now removed)
We actually don't need to go via $l^2$ thanks to this solution.

Comment: Thanks! The use of $\ell^2$-spaces can indeed be avoided (which is why I edited the answer), but it gives a good intuition why the statement is true: if $S_1 \hookrightarrow S_2$, we can also expect $\ell^2(S_1) \hookrightarrow \ell^2(S_2)$.

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person Let me know if I can clarify something.